# This code is suppose to extract contact person and fax number looks okay but does not work

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, bots

The result is this (but there are results on the site)

> ```py
> Contact Person: None
> Fax Number: None
> Contact Person: None.
> ```

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_contact_person_and_fax_number(url):
    # Send GET request to link url
    link_response = requests.get(url)

    # Parse HTML content with BeautifulSoup
    link_soup = BeautifulSoup(link_response.content, "html.parser")

    # Find the contact person and fax number
    contact_person = None
    fax_number = None
    contact_div = link_soup.find("div", {"class": "info-gen-box clearfix"})
    if contact_div:
        contact_person = contact_div.find("div", {"class": "info-gen-box clearfix"})
        if contact_person:
            contact_person = contact_person.text.strip()
        fax_number = contact_div.find("div", {"class": "info-fax info-mar"})
        if fax_number:
            fax_number = fax_number.text.strip()

    return (contact_person, fax_number)


# Prompt user for NAICS code
naics_code = input("Enter NAICS code: ")

# Loop through all search result pages
for page_num in range(1, 81):
    # Send GET request to search page
    page_url = f"https://www.usaopps.com/government_contractors/search.htm?naics={naics_code}&page={page_num}"
    page_response = requests.get(page_url)

    # Parse HTML content with BeautifulSoup
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")

    # Find all search results on current page
    results = page_soup.select(".lr-title")
    links = page_soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'lr-title'})

    # Loop through each search result link and extract contact person and fax number if available
    for link in links:
        # Extract link url
        url = link.find('a').get('href')

        if not url.startswith('http'):
            url = f"https://www.usaopps.com{url}"

        # Get contact person and fax number for this link
        contact_person, fax_number = get_contact_person_and_fax_number(url)

        # Print results
        print(f"Contact Person: {contact_person}")
        print(f"Fax Number: {fax_number}")
```

Answer (score 1):

This section seems to be the problem to me. Once the contact_div is set, there isn't another div of the same class inside ... in fact, looking at the site, this isn't how it's set up anymore. Did it change since you started this?

```
contact_div = link_soup.find("div", {"class": "info-gen-box clearfix"})
if contact_div:
    contact_person = contact_div.find("div", {"class": "info-gen-box clearfix"})
    if contact_person:
        contact_person = contact_person.text.strip()
    fax_number = contact_div.find("div", {"class": "info-fax info-mar"})
    if fax_number:
        fax_number = fax_number.text.strip()
```

I see only one `<div class="info-gen-box clearfix">` and it closes before the `info-fax info-mar` div that you are trying to access inside it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Reason Behind the Missing Information

In `get_contact_person_and_fax_number` you have

> ```py
>     contact_div = link_soup.find("div", {"class": "info-gen-box clearfix"})
>     if contact_div:
>         contact_person = contact_div.find("div", {"class": "info-gen-box clearfix"})
> ```
>
> ```py
>         fax_number = contact_div.find("div", {"class": "info-fax info-mar"})
> ```

However, there is no nested `div.info-gen-box.clearfix`<sup>([view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CPue.png))</sup> on these pages (was that a typo?) and `div.info-fax.info-mar`<sup>([view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NszKg.png))</sup> is not inside *`contact_div`* (you could just have `fax_number=link_soup.find("div",{"class":"info-fax info-mar"})` **outside** the *`if contact_div`* block).

---

#### Suggested Solution

Below is my suggested version of `get_contact_person_and_fax_number`<sup>([view example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2LNI.png))</sup>

```py
def get_company_info(compUrl, pre_print=''):
    # Fetch and Parse HTML content with requests + BeautifulSoup
    lSoup = BeautifulSoup((lr:=requests.get(compUrl)).content, "html.parser")

    # Find the side box and zip together dt/dd tags with company info
    contact_div = lSoup.select_one('div[id="box-sideinfo"] dl:has(dt+dd)') 
    ckv = zip(
        contact_div.select('dt:has(+dd)'), contact_div.select('dt+dd')
    ) if contact_div else [] ## use empty list if container is not found 
    
    # Build a dictionary from zip
    get_k = lambda dx: ' '.join(dx.get_text(' ').split()).strip(':') ## [minimal spacing]
    def get_v(dx):
        if dx.find('dd'): return list(dx.stripped_strings)[0] ## for nested info
        return dx.get_text(' • ', strip=True)
    company_dets = {get_k(dt): get_v(dd) for dt,dd in ckv} ## [dict comprehension]

    # Print and Return
    lrStat = f'<[{lr.status_code} {lr.reason}]> in {lr.elapsed} from {lr.url}'
    if isinstance(pre_print, str):
        print(pre_print + f'{len(company_dets)} company details - {lrStat}')
    if not contact_div: company_dets['Error Message'] = f'No info - {lrStat}'
    return company_dets if company_dets else {'msg': f'!Error! No info - {lrStat}'}

def get_contact_person_and_fax_number(url):
    cDets = get_company_info(url, None)
    return (cDets.get('Contact Person'), cDets.get('Fax'))
```

You could also directly use `get_company_info` in *`for link in links:`*<sup>([view example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCRhM.png))</sup>

```py
        # if not url.startswith('http'): url = f"https://www.usaopps.com{url}"

        # Print contact person and fax number for this link
        keys_list, company_info = ['Contact Person', 'Fax'], get_company_info(url) #, None)
        for k in keys_list: print(f'    {k}: {company_info.get(k)}')
```

---

##### Other Suggestions

These are not essential, but I have some recommendations/notes about your *`for page_num...`* loop:

- imo it would be safer to have

  ```py
      for link in page_soup.select('div.lr-title:has(a[href])'):
          url = link.find('a', href=True)['href']
  ```

  - [btw, why do you have `results` and `links`, which I expect are the same ResultSet, especially since you don't see to be using `results` for anything?]
- there should be something to stop the loop after the last page, otherwise you could be unnecessarily sending requests to pages without results; either

  - just `if not links: break` to stop as soon as you get to a page without results
  - or use a `while` loop with two conditions [demonstrated below]

```py
# Prompt user for NAICS code and build page 1 URL
naics_code = input("Enter NAICS code: ")
page_url = f"https://www.usaopps.com/government_contractors/search.htm?naics={naics_code}"

# Begin while loop
all_rows, pg_num, max_pgs = [], 0, 81
# max_pgs = int(max_pgs) if (max_pgs:=input('Page limit:')).isdigit() else None
while page_url and (pg_num:=pg_num+1)<=(max_pgs if max_pgs else pg_num):
    if not page_url.startswith('http'): page_url = f"https://www.usaopps.com{page_url}"
    pgSoup = BeautifulSoup((pr:=requests.get(page_url)).content, "html.parser")
    llen = len(links := pgSoup.select('div.lr-title:has(a[href])'))

    ## JUST FOR PRINTING PROGRESS (how many results and which page)
    abtRes = pgSoup.select('div.list-total,div.list-head>h2')[:2]
    pgProgressPlus = ' for '.join([p.get_text(' ',strip=True) for p in abtRes])
    print(f'[Page {pg_num}][{llen} Links]', pgProgressPlus, '\n')

    # Loop through and scrape result links while printing and/or collecting company info
    for ln, link in enumerate(links,1):
        url = link.find('a', href=True)['href']
        if not url.startswith('http'): url = f"https://www.usaopps.com{url}"

        # all_rows.append(company_info:=get_company_info(url,None)) ## collect data
        company_info = get_company_info(url, f'\n  [Page {pg_num}][Link {ln} of {llen}]')
        
        # for k,v in company_info.items():print(f'      {k}: {v}') ## print all
        keys_list = ['Contact Person','Fax']
        for k in keys_list: print(f'      {k}: {company_info.get(k)}')
    
    # Find next page link and update for next loop
    next_link = pgSoup.select_one('span.page-link a[href]:-soup-contains("Next")')
    page_url = next_link['href'] if next_link else None
    print('\n\n')
```

If you uncomment the *`## collect data`* line, the collected data would be something like [image: opdf]